# Rails Active Record Query to push two active record relation objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
first_user = User.first
last_user = User.last
```

How to add two relation object ? 
This does not work.

```
my_users = first_user + last_user
```

I can use array and push the first and last user.
But pagination will not work for array

```
users = my_users.paginate# (using will_paginate)
```

But this works

```
users = User.limit(2).paginate
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to paginate a bunch of comments. User will search for user name . Search result will give me matching users. And for every user , I have to collect all their comments and paginate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, but makes at least three SQL calls:

```
first_user = User.first
last_user = User.last
users = User.where(id: [first_user.id, last_user.id]).paginate
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to paginate the first user and last user comments  actually. Any way ?

Comment: I don't see you mentioning that in your question. You should have mentioned that as well, however, you can do: `Comment.where(user_id: [first_user.id, last_user.id]).paginate`

Comment: Thank you Suriya. Yes, should have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add two objects,it should be in array format always then only you can do pagination using will paginate.

you have to follow the below step

```
 user_all = [] 

 first_user = User.first 

 last_user = User.last 

 user_all << first_user

 user_all << last_user

 users = user_all.paginate
```

Comment: user_all is array. we can use limit on that

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `limit' for #<Array:0x007ff0346188a8>